# how to add Breadcrumbs for grails 3

Tags: grails

is there any plugins available to add dynamic bread crumb for grails. could you provide any example? i am using grails 3.3.0.
following plugins are not working.
https://grails.org/plugin/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin.

i am getting the following error. 
    | Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:breadcrumbs:0.5.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/breadcrumbs/0.5.2/breadcrumbs-0.5.2.pom
    file:.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/breadcrumbs/0.5.2/breadcrumbs-0.5.2.jar

Comment: The link you provided is to the Grails 2 plugin repository. You can find Grails 3 plugins here http://plugins.grails.org/

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Grails 3, you need to add

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin:1.0.2"
```

to `build.gradle` and execute `grails clean` to rebuild the project.

Comment: I added "compile "org.grails.plugins:groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin:1.0.2"" into build.gradle  file and ran grails clean. it is giving the following error.

Comment: sorry I added  maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }
build was successfull

Comment: error: C:\myproject>grails install-plugin groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
| Error Command not found install-plugin

Comment: this is the message I got when I runt install-plugin. I checked in .M2/repository/org.grails.plugins ...folder. there is no plugin installed for breadcrumps

Comment: plugin was not installed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only searching your local repository...  make sure you have the maven repository which hosts the plugin in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }
}
```